# add values for a range between reference date minus 6 days in excel

Tags: excel, date, range, vlookup

i would like to add the corresponding values of dates with reference to a particular date and -6 days in excel.

For example: reference date is 10th feb 15. I would like to add values under flight time column for dates ranging between 10th feb 15 and previous 6 days.

similarly add values for a reference date and previous 30 days values and 1 year values.

Comment: Well, doing date math in Excel is pretty easy, just do your date - # .. so if your Feb 10, 2015 date is in cell A1.  in Cell B1:  =A1-1    That'll give you the previous day.   =A1-2 ... that's 2 days ago.  How do you want this displayed? Showing Day-1 in Col B, Day-2 in Col C, etc is pretty easy, however, not sure that's what you're after?  Can you show a table in your original post showing expected results ?

Answer (score 0):

What i wanted was, sum all the flight timings of a particular date in column A. I used the sumifs formula to achieve this.

The formula is =SUMIFS($I$8:$I$1122,$A$8:$A$1122,"<="&C8,$A$8:$A$1122,">="&C8-6)

What it does: Here the reference cell is C8 which is 6th Feb 14
              step 1- date range for the calculation is 6th feb 14 minus 6 days
              step 2- add the values of column I which correspond to all the           dates that fall within 6th feb 14 to 31st jan 14
              step 3- indicate the sum in column K

Unfortunately i cannot include any pictures or files to show what i have mentioned due to site limitations.